# TLSv1.2 with Java 7 and Wildlfy 8 - handshake_failure

Tags: java, security, java-7, wildfly, tls1.2

In our application we need send some data to foreign customer server web service JAX-WS. I generated required client files from WSDL with using `wsimport`. Then I tried connect to server side web service. But with Java 1.7.0_67 64bit connection wasn't successfull. When I change JAVA_HOME, Eclipse Java configuration and Wildfly 8 Runtime environment to  Java 8, it was successfull.

By https://www.ssllabs.com server support only TLSv1.2. Therefore I mean that Java 8 hasn't problem connect on this, because I think that Java 8 use implicit TLSv1.2. So for Java 7 I tried set using TLSv1.2. I made this with:

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

or

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

or I try set `https.protocols` via `System.setProperty()`.

Ok, after these settings, in log looks as comunication starts use TLSv1.2. But on point `RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure` it looks as using version TLSv1. Shortended Log:

```
//SOME ADDINGS TRUSTED CERT

12:42:00,426 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

12:42:00,426 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256


//SOME ANOTHER  Ignoring unsupported cipher suite messages

12:42:00,526 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Allow legacy hello messages: true
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Is initial handshake: true
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Is secure renegotiation: false

    12:42:00,528 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, setSoTimeout(60000) called

    12:42:00,533 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) %% No cached client session

    12:42:00,540 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2

12:42:00,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) RandomCookie:  GMT: 1437570568 bytes = { 40, 32, 41, 207, 219, 45, 44, 254, 211, 5, 213, 185, 140, 88, 46, 94, 49, 236, 52, 25, 75, 221, 38, 210, 90, 95, 156, 61 }

12:42:00,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Session ID:  {}

12:42:00,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]

12:42:00,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Compression Methods:  { 0 }

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: app.bundesnetzagentur.de]

12:42:00,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) ***

12:42:00,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 226


// SOME HASHES

12:42:00,631 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [Raw read]: length = 5

12:42:00,632 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) 0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....

12:42:00,633 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [Raw read]: length = 2

12:42:00,633 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) 0000: 02 28                                              .(

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called closeSocket()

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called close()

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called closeInternal(true)

12:42:00,637 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-27) Interceptor for {https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas}WS_VersUnterbrechungGas#{https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas}BeginnTransaktion has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.beginnTransaktion(Unknown Source)
    at de.ids.mabiplus.bna.jaxws.web.BnaExportJaxwsAction.execute(BnaExportJaxwsAction.java:37) [acosnms-om-java-3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.mabi.client.common.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:77) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.umgr.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.utils.i18n.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:107) [wega-utils-web-0.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.platform.commons.web.ServiceFilter.doFilter(ServiceFilter.java:51) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas/WS_VersUnterbrechungGas.asmx: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1347)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1331)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1290)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1246)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1303)
    ... 62 more

12:42:00,646 WARN  [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] (default task-27) Unhandled Exception thrown: class javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
12:42:00,647 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-27) UT005023: Exception handling request to /acosNms/om/outagesToBna.do: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.mabi.client.common.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:77) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.umgr.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.utils.i18n.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:107) [wega-utils-web-0.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.platform.commons.web.ServiceFilter.doFilter(ServiceFilter.java:51) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.beginnTransaktion(Unknown Source)
    at de.ids.mabiplus.bna.jaxws.web.BnaExportJaxwsAction.execute(BnaExportJaxwsAction.java:37) [acosnms-om-java-3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas/WS_VersUnterbrechungGas.asmx: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1347)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1331)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1290)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1246)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1303)
    .. more 62
```

For solve problems with `Ignoring unsupported cipher suite` I installed Unlimited JCEPolicy JDK7. But some still remained. But I think that problem is that on row `RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure` is used older and server unsupported TLSv1 version. But why on this point is change this version? Is possible some settings for ONLY TLSv1.2 use? Or is possible that problem is elsewhere? Very thanks for help !

**EDIT:** By @dave_thompson_085 comment below, this looks as that "Java 7 JSSE is Ignoring SHA2 suites as unsupported". For more information you can see this comment. And I forget mean that for Java 8, which worked right, I added `jssecacert` file into /lib/security. This file I generated by `InstallCert`
. But with Java 7 I get similiar error as in application during obtaining certificate via InstallCert. But I think that is not relate with my problem, because my `handshake_failure` is other type of problem than `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` which I got with Java 8 before than I add jssecacerts file into /lib/security.

Comment: This may be of use for a workaround. http://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7

Comment: (1) The logging `RECV TLSv1 ALERT:` is mistaken (perhaps just old code); the 'raw read' shows `15 03 03 00 02 / 02 28` which is TLSv1.2 as expected and desired. (2) SSLLabs shows this server requires 1.2 and *only four ciphersuites*: ECDHE_RSA with AES (GCM or CBC) *and SHA2-family* hashes. As your log shows and I can reproduce on 7u80, for some reason Java 7 JSSE is `Ignoring` SHA2 suites as `unsupported` (even with Unlimited Policy, which doesn't matter for hash anyway only for cipher); I don't think it should and will try to investigate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ok, information that "RECV TLSv1 ALERT" is only mistake and really is use TLSv1.2 is very important for me, so I can focus on your point (2). Thanks. And when you get some idea about your second point, please put this here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem already. How I stated in my EDIT, and @dave_thompson_085 told in his comment, wrong version of TLS in `RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal` is maybe only log bug. So whole communication was realized in TLSv1.2. But problem was with `Ignoring unsupported cipher suite` some ciphers what I need. Even if I used Unlimited JCEPolicy JDK7. But for enable these ciphers I must add `https.cipherSuites` with these ciphers into VM arguments too. So when somebody will have problem with unsupported ciphers which should supported in some Java version, will be good try add this VM argument. Article about this:
http://fsanglier.blogspot.cz/2015/04/java-7-and-tlsv12-supported-but-not-enabled.html

and my related question where about this:
[Java 7 does not support ciphers which should be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186258/java-7-does-not-support-ciphers-which-should-be-supported?noredirect=1#comment58103681_35186258)

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 only supports TLSv1 and not TLSv1.2.

As well as the well known scanning tool, SSL Labs also has a nice "User Agent Cabailities" section:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Here's the detail for Java 7
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Java&version=7u25

This should also have shown up under the the site scan report that Java 7 wouldn't be able to connect.

Comment: You write that "Java 7 only supports TLSv1 and not TLSv1.2", but I think that is not exactly true. By some sources, TLSv1.2 is default disabled in Java7, but can be enabled. F.e. https://community.qualys.com/thread/12361

Comment: From the bottom of the SSLLabs page: "(**) Tested with default settings. Some platforms can be manually configured to enable more features and better security. " Java 7 JSSE client does support TLSv1.1 and 1.2 but does not enable them by default; Java 8 in contrast does enable them.