# Java 7 does not support ciphers which should be supported

Tags: java, security, encryption, java-7, tls1.2

I need connect to  foreign server via client side in JAX-WS. Client side run on Wildfly 8. With Java 8 is connection ok. But I have problem with connect to server in Java 7 (I tried u45,67,79). Properties of server side security is https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=app.bundesnetzagentur.de

In part "Cipher Suites" are four ciphers. **GCM** ciphers should not be supported in Java 7 by source http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote1-1
respectivly by source with enlarged table of Java versions
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote1-1

Ok, but two ciphers **CBC** should be supoorted by the same source as above. In these sources are note, that these ciphers require TLSv1.2 or higher. But I use this version. And yes, I put two files from **UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7** into /lib/security folder of my Java. But in log I see some about "Ignoring unsupported cipher suite" yet. And my connection end with hanshake failure. This is shortended log:

```
//SOME ADDINGS TRUSTED CERT

12:42:00,426 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

12:42:00,426 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

//SOME ANOTHER  Ignoring unsupported cipher suite messages

12:42:00,526 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Allow legacy hello messages: true
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Is initial handshake: true
    12:42:00,527 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Is secure renegotiation: false

    12:42:00,528 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, setSoTimeout(60000) called

    12:42:00,533 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) %% No cached client session

    12:42:00,540 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2

12:42:00,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) RandomCookie:  GMT: 1437570568 bytes = { 40, 32, 41, 207, 219, 45, 44, 254, 211, 5, 213, 185, 140, 88, 46, 94, 49, 236, 52, 25, 75, 221, 38, 210, 90, 95, 156, 61 }

12:42:00,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Session ID:  {}

12:42:00,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]

12:42:00,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Compression Methods:  { 0 }

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA

12:42:00,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: app.bundesnetzagentur.de]

12:42:00,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) ***

12:42:00,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 226


    // SOME HASHES

10:43:37,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 226

10:43:37,112 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [Raw write]: length = 231

// SOME HASHES

12:42:00,631 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [Raw read]: length = 5

12:42:00,632 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) 0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....

12:42:00,633 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) [Raw read]: length = 2

12:42:00,633 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) 0000: 02 28                                              .(

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure

12:42:00,634 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called closeSocket()

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called close()

12:42:00,635 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) default task-27, called closeInternal(true)

12:42:00,637 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-27) Interceptor for {https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas}WS_VersUnterbrechungGas#{https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas}BeginnTransaktion has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.beginnTransaktion(Unknown Source)
    at de.ids.mabiplus.bna.jaxws.web.BnaExportJaxwsAction.execute(BnaExportJaxwsAction.java:37) [acosnms-om-java-3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.mabi.client.common.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:77) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.umgr.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.utils.i18n.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:107) [wega-utils-web-0.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.platform.commons.web.ServiceFilter.doFilter(ServiceFilter.java:51) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas/WS_VersUnterbrechungGas.asmx: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1347)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1331)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1290)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1246)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1303)
    ... 62 more

12:42:00,646 WARN  [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] (default task-27) Unhandled Exception thrown: class javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
12:42:00,647 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-27) UT005023: Exception handling request to /acosNms/om/outagesToBna.do: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.mabi.client.common.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:77) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.umgr.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.utils.i18n.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:107) [wega-utils-web-0.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at de.ids.gaja.platform.commons.web.ServiceFilter.doFilter(ServiceFilter.java:51) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.beginnTransaktion(Unknown Source)
    at de.ids.mabiplus.bna.jaxws.web.BnaExportJaxwsAction.execute(BnaExportJaxwsAction.java:37) [acosnms-om-java-3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://app.bundesnetzagentur.de/WS_VersorgUnterbrGas/WS_VersUnterbrechungGas.asmx: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1347)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1331)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1290)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1246)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1303)
    .. more 62
```

So why these two ciphers are not supported? And is it reason of this hanshake failure? When I will not resolve this with JSSE, is possible made this with some other library, f.e BountyCastle? Very thanks for help.

Comment: So are you using TLSv1.2? Does the trace show that?

Comment: @ EJP I mean that I use TLSv1.2 because in log are on many places "TLSv1.2", f.e about "ClientHello". And I start app with -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 for enable TLS1v2 in Java 7. I know that in point "RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure" is version "TLSv1", but in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153912/tlsv1-2-with-java-7-and-wildlfy-8-handshake-failure I was warned that is only log bug by comment from @ dave_thompson_085.

Comment: You should upgrade to Java 8 regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you can alter code that creates SSLContext to specify TLSv1.2, you'll have to upgrade to Java 8.

See for example, http://fsanglier.blogspot.com/2015/04/java-7-and-tlsv12-supported-but-not-enabled.html

Comment: I've answered the question before, with the same outcome. BTW, Java 7 is not supported anymore, so everybody should upgrade even if the ciphersuite would be supported.

Comment: @Nicholas Sushkin Many many thanks you ! I have solve this. Your referenced article help me. I don't use SSLContext, I call server via JAX-WS client side web service. But in this aricle is stated **https.cipherSuites** VM argument. So when I use this for required ciphers, it works. Many thanks !